# How to Install s3cmd in Amazon EMR instance

Tags: amazon-s3, emr, amazon-emr, s3cmd

I am building an **Apache Spark** application which be executed in an [EMR](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticmapreduce/) instance .For that I am creating a cluster and after that I am adding steps into cluster for execution of Spark application.

In Spark Application I need to perform read/write operations into S3 .
For interaction with S3 services I need to install **s3cmd** in **EMR instance**.
Also while creating EMR cluster I need to **install and configure s3cmd using --bootstrap-application**

But I need details regarding how to install and configure s3cmd using bootstrap-application

Please provide me appropriate information regarding it

Answer (score 2):

https://dbaumgartel.wordpress.com/2014/04/10/an-elastic-mapreduce-streaming-example-with-python-and-ngrams-on-aws/

gives an example of pushing python scripts to S3 (using s3cmd on your local computer) which are used in the EMR application.  You then push your source data to S3, and the EMR application puts is results into S3.  You can use s3cmd on your local computer to push the source data and download the results.

If your source data is already in S3 or elsewhere in AWS, you can always create a new EC2 instance in which to run s3cmd to get the data into the right S3 bucket for processing.

Answer (score 0):

Use custom bootstrap action.

> "Bootstrap actions are scripts that are run on the cluster nodes when
>   Amazon EMR launches the cluster. They run before Hadoop starts and
>   before the node begins processing data."

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/emr-plan-bootstrap.html#bootstrapCustom

Comment: put commands to install all the softwares you need in .sh bootstrap file